# how to make all fields clear when application starts iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I've 5 labels and 2 text fields in my iphone application when i end the application and restarts it the label and  text fields will contain perviously used data. I want to make it clear all labels and text fields when application starts please any one help me Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you persisting values and re-populating them when your app launches? Or are you just seeing the expected behavior of multi-tasking? If the latter, it's generally poor user experience to delete the user's data!

Comment: No its just like conversion app in which i don't need data to be displayed in labels r text fields when relaunch the application

Comment: Sorry I maybe didn't make my question clear - when you say 'relaunch' do you mean 'completely fresh launch of application' (in which case it would seem that you would be doing something special to persist the fields), or do you mean 'returning from the background'?

Comment: ok i did this, i build and ran my application on simulator at that time all labels was clear and i stopped application and this time i launched application in simulator now I'm getting above prob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of fields and labels nil i.e label.text = @""; in ViewWillAppear it'll clear fields and labels when come back to tab.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the fields as nil in `ViewWillAppear` or in `ViewDidLoad` methods.

Comment: i did before like label.text = nil; in both methods but it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code:

```
textFieldname.stringValue = @"";
```

Comment: The question is about Objective-C and cocoa, not javascript

Answer (score 0):

Do this in viewwillappear method:

```
  label.text = @""; //and all other labels  
  txt.text = @""; //and all other textFields
```